# Проблема с перекрытием модуля модулем при объявлении

Tags: delphi, модули

Есть компонент *StringGrid1*, у него есть событие

```
StringGrid1DrawCell(Sender: TObject; ACol, ARow: Integer; Rect: TRect;
State: TGridDrawState);
```

параметр «*State*» у него описан в *Vcl.Grids.TGridDrawState*.

Я в программе также пользуюсь библиотекой *EhLib*, и ее объявление (*GridsEh*) конечно располагается после *Vcl.Grids*. из-за этого конечно неправильно срабатывает данное событие, которые берет данные из «*GridsEh*» (*GridEh.TGridDrawState*).

Тогда я написал конкретно путь:

> procedure TFMain.StringGrid1DrawCell(Sender: TObject; ACol, ARow:
>   Integer; Rect: TRect; State: **Vcl.Grids.TGridDrawState**);

Но на строке

```
if gdFixed in State then
```

в этом же, теперрь вылазит ошибка:

> E2008 Incompatible types

Что я делаю не так?

Вообще **ПЕРВОНОЧАЛЬНО** процедура выглядела так:

```
procedure TForm1.StringGrid1DrawCell(Sender: TObject; ACol, ARow: Integer;
    Rect: TRect; State: TGridDrawState);
var
  Format : Word;
  s : string;
begin
  with Sender as TStringGrid do
    if gdFixed in State then
    begin
      if ACol < FHeaders.Count then
        s := FHeaders[ACol];

      Format := DT_LEFT or DT_WORDBREAK;
      OffsetRect(Rect, 2, 2);
      DrawText(Canvas.Handle, s, Length(s), Rect, Format);
    end;

end;
```

Comment: нет там я поменял (я в двух местах поменял), я в объявлении поменял и тут уже на месте поменял.
После этого у меня ошибка вылазит.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Хотя с `EhLib` никогда не работал, я предполагаю, что следует указать вместо
`if gdFixed in State then`
сие:
`if Vcl.Grids.gdFixed in State then`.

Таким образом мы дадим компилятору точный путь откуда брать данные.